# How do i display grand total in place of subtotal in minicart magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to display grand total in mini cart in place of subtotal in magento 2 porto theme.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

**Method : 1**

You need to override below files

- Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
- Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php

1) minicart.phtml

```
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <span class="total-price grand-total" data-bind="html: getCartParam('grand_total')"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

2) Cart.php

Override `getSectionData()` function

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
    $grand_total = $totals['grand_total']->getValue();

    return [
        'grand_total' => $grand_total ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($grand_total) : '',
    ];
}
```

**Method : 2**

You need to override below files

- Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
- Add plugin in `di.xml`

1) minicart.phtml

```
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <span class="total-price grand-total" data-bind="html: getCartParam('grand_total')"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

2) Add plugin to `di.xml` and create plugin file on mentioned location

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="cart_totals" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\CartTotals"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Create `CartTotals.php` file on above mentioned location.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;
class CartTotals
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    /**
     * Add cart grand total to result data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {
        $totals = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getTotals();
        if(isset($totals['grand_total'])) {
            $result['grand_total'] = $totals['grand_total']->getValueInclTax() ?: $totals['grand_total']->getValue();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```